# Removing sub key from plist (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

I'm new to Objective-C so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to figure out how to remove a sub key and value in a plist file. For example, the contents of the plist file are below:

[image]

The keys in the dictionary under 'Network Services' is what I'm trying to remove (just one of them) and their associated values.

Strangely my code can delete 'CurrentSet', 'Model', and 'NetworkServices', but I just can't seem to delve down a further level to remove any of the keys.

```
NSError *error;

NSString *filepath = @"/Users/myHomeFolder/Desktop/preferences.plist";

NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat;

NSDictionary *dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/myHomeFolder/Desktop/preferences.plist"] options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&plistFormat error:&error];

[dict removeObjectForKey:@"2236EA34-D3CC-4C5E-8F9C-91F3639EC60E"];

[dict writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

In the code above I'm trying to delete the key '2236EA34-D3CC-4C5E-8F9C-91F3639EC60E'.

I'll just say that this is purely in the interest of curiosity. I realise that there may be other tools out there that would make this easier, but I'm trying to specifically learn Objective-C and I feel the best way to learn is to investigate as much as possible.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the nested dictionary:

`[[dict valueForKey:@"NetworkServices] removeObjectForKey:@"2236EA34-D3CC-4C5E-8F9C-91F3639EC60E"]]`

This requires `NSMutableDictionaries`.

Also, for app preferences storage, you should be using [`[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html).

If you use `NSUserDefaults` you will be able to specify a key path using a dot separator:

`@"NetworkServices.2236EA34-D3CC-4C5E-8F9C-91F3639EC60E"`

Comment: Great stuff! And so simple!. I'll look into using NSUserDefaults. Many thanks for the help.